# Angular Material intellisense doesn't work in VSCode

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular-material

I'm working on an `Angular` (v13) project and I installed `Angular` `Material` using this command

```
ng add @angular/material
```

I can see the package in the node_modules, but in `VSCode`, the intellisense/auto-import don't work at all for a `typescript` file, but it works with any other package.

It's not the first time I'm having this issue with `Angular` `Material`, but I never found a solution.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same issue just now on V13. Adding the following line to `tsconfig.json` fixed it for me (goes under "compilerOptions"):

```
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@angular/material"]
```

[image: VSCode Intellisense MAterial]

Answer (score 2):

ok I've found the issue. To have the intellisense working, I had to import the `material module` in my `angular module`, then I can see the intellisense in the `component` code.

[image]

Comment: Issue persist in Angular 17 and this solution works

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but you can try using an extension like (Angular Language Service) available here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template